# face recognition with pepper robot with simulator

Tags: robot, pepper

How can I configure pepper robot in choregraphe to detect face and recognise for the next time in simulator?

Getting Error as bellow.[[ERROR] behavior.box :**init**:8 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1139710186718928:/Learn Face_1/Learn Face_2:   ALProxy::ALProxy    Can't find service: ALFaceDetection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrA5U.png)

Comment: If the response solved your problem, please mark the response as answer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately choregraphe and its simulator don't include all the features, including face recognition or speech recognition. You will need a real robot to use this feature.